# Rails ActionCable API mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I am going to create Rails API that handles WebSocket based on ActionCable (first of all, it is good idea to use ActionCable in API mode ?). ActionCable works well for full stack Rails application but I encountered difficulties with API. The first question is what kind of format should have all requests to actionCable server. All I've found so far it is subscribe action:

```
{
  "command":"subscribe",
  "identifier":"{\"channel\":\"SomeChannel\"}"
}
```

How about others? Is there any documentation where I can find that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would consider the target client as well. I don't know if ActionCable has non-browser clients and it's possible that you want the Websocket API to be accessible also to native mobile apps (not just browsers)....? P.S. I'm biased, since I'm the author of iodine (the Ruby web socket server) and [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) (a real-time application framework built on iodine). I voted with my actions to leave websockets out of ActionCable's hands.

Comment: Yes my main goal is to handle just mobiles and I am wondering if ActionCable is appropriate to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably avoid using the ActionCable semantics and internal protocol for an API project that includes non-browser clients.

For example:

- ActionCable's internal semantics / protocol might change between versions. Since your code will be tightly coupled with ActionCable's internal workings, it might be harder to upgrade.
- ActionCable's internal semantics / protocol might or might not include everything you need, whereas writing your own Websocket messaging protocol (especially using JSON) is super easy and will offer you an exact fit.

This doesn't mean you need to completely move away from Rails. It should be easy enough to use your Rails models and code within a non-Rails Websocket alternative.

Also, Ruby has some nice Websocket alternatives for ActionCable.

I'm biased, being the author of both [Iodine - an HTTP/Websocket server with native Pub/Sub](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) and [Plezi.io, a real-time web application framework](http://www.plezi.io)... but I would probably use iodine (with or without the added comfort offered by Plezi).

A simple Websocket application with Plezi will look something like this (seriously, run the following code from the terminal using `irb`, it works):

```
require 'plezi'
class ChatServer
  def index
    "Use Websockets to connect."
  end
  def on_open
    @name = params['id'] || "anonymmous"
    subscribe channel: "chat"
    publish channel: "chat", message: "#{@name} joind the chat."
    write "Welcome, #{@name}!"
  end
  def on_close
    publish channel: "chat", message: "#{@name} left the chat."
  end
  def on_message data
    publish channel: "chat", message: "#{@name}: #{data}"
  end
  def on_shutdown
    write "Server shutting down. Goodbye #{@name}"
  end
end
Plezi.route '/', ChatServer

# We'll monitor message just for kicks:
subscription = Iodine.subscribe(pattern: "*") do |channel, message|
  # print a log?
  puts "\n* Message on channel #{channel}:\n#{message}\n"
end
# make sure we don't duplicate our monitoring on every process.
root_pid = Process.pid
Iodine.run { Iodine.unsubscribe(subscription) unless Process.pid == root_pid }

exit
```

No Redis server required, no special things to prepare and it's possible to use plezi as middleware within a Rails application (running the `iodine` server instead of `puma`).